# Alguien que es/fuera diagnosticado positivo

Tags: gramática

¿Cuál es la diferencia de significado entre las construcciones "alguien que es diagnosticado positivo" y "alguien que fuera diagnosticado positivo", en el contexto "[recibir notificaciones si has estado en contacto con alguien que fuera diagnosticado positivo](https://radarcovid.gob.es/home)" ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este tipo de construcciones, se puede usar indicativo o subjuntivo:

1. Indicativo:

1.a. Alguien que es diagnosticado positivo

1.b. Alguien que ha sido / fue diagnosticado positivo

1.c. Alguien que había sido diagnosticado positivo

2. Subjuntivo:

2.a. Alguien que sea diagnosticado positivo

2.b. Alguien que haya sido diagnosticado positivo

2.c. Alguien que hubiera sido diagnosticado positivo

Las opciones (a) se refieren al presente o al futuro, mientras que las opciones (b) y (c) se refieren al pasado.

El pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo "fuera" es un caso especial. Si bien es pretérito, se refiere al presente o al futuro y reemplaza al caído en desuso "fuere" (futuro del subjuntivo).

En la oración:

- Con la aplicación oficial del Gobierno de España podrás recibir notificaciones si has estado en contacto con alguien que fuera diagnosticado positivo por COVID-19.

podría usarse "es diagnosticado", "sea diagnosticado" o "fuera diagnosticado" para indicar que el diagnóstico es posterior al contacto (luego del contacto, se confirma un diagnóstico positivo y la persona es informada). La diferencia entre las tres formas radica en el grado de probabilidad: "es diagnosticado" es más probable que "sea diagnosticado" y esta forma es más probable que "fuera diagnosticado". Las tres formas son correctas pero se decidió usar "fuera" para indicar improbabilidad o, inclusive, indisposición ante la idea: en la eventualidad (remota o no deseada) de que la persona fuera diagnosticada positiva.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!